# Linux 'compose' key sequence extensions

Tags: linux, keymap, special-characters, compose-key

Compose key is a great way way to write all these ©–®—… stuff. It's really MUCH more handy than the windows "alt+0169" method.

Is there a way to define additional sequences? E.g. I'd like to have "Compose+-->" result in "→"

Comment: anybody knows how to make this work also on ubuntu 13.04? I do not manage to have it use the X11 files, nor to understand where the gnome configuration files are hiding (from my view!).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey) has some info about this. It looks like their instructions are fairly distribution-agnostic; however, I haven't tested them.

Comment: Great, that's it! Thanks! :)
In short, copy `cp /usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose ~/.XCompose` the file tou your home dir and edit it.

Comment: On Fedora 14 (and other versions), you'll also have to edit `/etc/X11/xinit/xinput.d/none.conf` and set `GTK_IM_MODULE=xim` so it'll stop ignoring `~/.XCompose`.  Of course, in order for changes to take effect, you'll have to log out and back in.  See [this post on FedoraForum.org](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showpost.php?p=1245448&postcount=6) for more info.