# how do I influence the compose rules in gnome?

Tags: linux, gnome, compose-key

this is a partial duplicate of the question [Linux 'compose' key sequence extensions](https://superuser.com/questions/87600/linux-compose-key-sequence-extensions):

I am using ubuntu 13.04 with unity and I would like to have a specific composition sequence to work as defined in the X11 rules (`<Multi_key> <acute> <c>` produces now "ç") and to add a new one (`<Multi_key> <z> <z>` to produce "ʒ")

my ~/.XCompose contains both above rules, but the above behaviour is not here yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default GTK input method, `gtk-im-context-simple`, uses a compiled-in list of Compose sequences. You will need to make it use the XIM module.

Add this line to your `~/.xprofile` file, then log out and log in again:

```
export GTK_IM_MODULE='xim'
```

To undo, remove the line.

Comment: 'compiled-in list', you really mean that there's a piece of software that defines a hard-coded list? do you know anything more about it? I'd like to file a bug about the (wrong) behaviour of compose acute c, but I do not know who to alert about it.

Comment: @mariotomo: Yes. When GTK is being compiled, the default X11 `Compose` file is transformed by a script into a C header [`gtkimcontextsimpleseqs.h`](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/gtk/gtkimcontextsimpleseqs.h), which becomes part of the compiled input method. See also the comments at the top of that file. Bug reports go to [GNOME Bugzilla for `gtk+`](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=gtk%2B).

Comment: @mariotomo: However, it seems that the header is only regenerated manually every now and then, so it might have gotten out-of-date.

Comment: but this way I cannot use shift-ctrl-u to type in an arbitrary unicode character, can I?

Comment: and there is no way to alter it once it has been compiled? no extra configuration files?

Comment: No. If you want to configure it, use `xim` (X11's default input module).

Comment: regarding the custom composition rules, I find your answer perfect, but for the ć, I have opened this bug report. https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=705168. maybe you have some ideas/corrections about it?