# Finding X11 UTF GB files

Tags: linux, xorg, special-characters, keymap, compose-key

I am using Linux Mint, and want to edit my compose keys according to the instructions given [here](https://superuser.com/questions/87600/linux-compose-key-sequence-extensions). My keyboard settings are English (UK). However, in the folder /usr/share/X11/locale where I expect to find a en_GB folder, the only english folder I can find is for en_US (which I edited without thinking, and it obviously didn't work).

Where can I find my folder, given that I would expect it to be in here?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to superuser.

You do not seem to have en_GB locales installed otherwise it should be exactly where you have been expecting it to be. The standard way of doing that is to edit `/etc/locale.gen` and comment in one or more of the `en_GB...` locales after which you will have to run (with sudo or as root)

```
locale-gen
```

On Debian-like systems such as Mint, you can apparently alternatively also just install `locales-all`. See [this answer on unix.stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/117611/199642).